# VFD max current rating less than motor peak current - problem?

Tags: vfd

Whats the worst that could happen if using a QUALITY 8amp VFD - single phase input, 230v, vector controlled - on a industrial 3 phase motor with peak current rating of 50 amps. Do VFDs have the potential to protect themselves lol? What would break first? And in what situation would that be likely ? Feel free to ask any motor spec..

The motor is a Bosch PMSM -

[image]

It might be overkill for a mini lathe project but useful to have any way )
Can you perceive any limitations / deviations from spec from driving this via VFD (thats allows to enter back current EMF constant) from 230v 50hz household supply ?

This video go me interested - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Un-uvkEhPEI&t=41s

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: The VFD can control the startup current of the motor, so what is the nameplate Wattage rating  and FLC (full load current)? If overloaded, the VFD will simply shutdown and display an error. The average VFD is designed to be pretty robust, so you'd have to do something rather nasty to kill it - like putting 460VAC into a 230VAC VFD.

Comment: Well, when you commission (setup) a VFD, you have to enter the motor rated current. An 8 Amp VFD will probably not allow you to enter 50 amps as a rated current. So you will have to lie to the VFD to have any chance of getting it to work. If you operate the VFD in V/F mode it may very well be able to start up the motor and slowly accelerate it to full speed if there is no mechanical load on the motor. But no guarantees.

Comment: The motor specs say that the rated current is 7.7 amps at 380 volts. The 50 amp peak current rating must be a very short term overload rating and may represent the peak of the waveform. I would expect that an 8 amp continuous-rated VFD could operate that motor. The VFD must be designed for a PMSM. I expect there are general purpose VFD's that are rated for either SCIMs or PMSMs. You may or may not find a VFD for 230V 1 ph input and 380V 3 ph output. I would be interested to see the complete motor spec.

Comment: Note that the YouTube link project includes Bosch Rexroth 5610 vector inverter and Bosch Rexroth MSK040C motor.

Comment: I hope the OP is sitting down when he sees the price! A bit more than 60quid methinks

Comment: I just bought 3 of these on ebay for £100 lol. They may well be scrap but won't know till they're tested. Do you think the Bosch Rexroth 5610 will be able to make these things move or just that there will be limitations? Heres the link address for the  pdf (requires download)- http://www.boschrexroth.com/various/utilities/mediadirectory/download/index.jsp?object_nr=R912005854 - If anyones interested page 55 is the spec. (apologies for my initial smugness I thought someone else bought them till I realised it was me!)

Comment: I am too lazy to read the VFD data. This motor can probably be used with a 1 HP (750 W) VFD right on up to several HP (several KW). VFD must be designed to support PMSM motors, which quite a few are nowadays. Note that VFD's typically don't have great support for PMSM. Not like a servodrive. What you really want for this motor is a compatible servodrive, I think. A lot of VFD's  allow you to program in a higher current/torque limit for lower speeds.

Comment: Done a bit of reading , yes this makes more sense now, these type of motors are perfect for CNCs and the correct servo drive can control any parameters (position control may be very useful later). I just realised I removed the motor model, its - Rexroth / Indramat MKD071B-061-KG0-KN. With servo drives we are getting more towards computer control / programming which Im much more comfortable with. Thanks mkeith. Also here is the motor spec (page61) - https://indramat-usa.com/uploads/2018/01/MKD-Project-Planning-Manual.pdf (3.4kw rated power)